# Signing a hash with DSS (Digital Signature Service)

Tags: java, pdfbox, digital-signature

I am trying to sign a PDF document with DSS, and my problem is that I cannot calculate the hash of the document in server A and then sign it in server B.

Knowing that server A contains the PDF document and in server B we retrieve the certificate used for signature

My question is how i can compute the hash of the document in a server A without needing the certificate. Then send it for signature in server B ?

UPDATE :

****** Preparation and calculation of hash ********

```
    IPdfObjFactory pdfObjFactory = new ServiceLoaderPdfObjFactory();
    PDFSignatureService pdfSignatureService = pdfObjFactory.newPAdESSignatureService();

    PAdESSignatureParameters parameters = new PAdESSignatureParameters();

    parameters.setDigestAlgorithm(DigestAlgorithm.SHA512);
    parameters.setReason("Preuve de signature");
    parameters.setLocation("MAROC");
    parameters.setGenerateTBSWithoutCertificate(true);

    SignatureImageParameters imageParameters = new SignatureImageParameters();

    imageParameters.setPage(1);
    FileDocument imageFile = new FileDocument("logo.png");
    RemoteDocument fileImage = RemoteDocumentConverter.toRemoteDocument(imageFile);
    DSSDocument image = RemoteDocumentConverter.toDSSDocument(fileImage);
    // set an image
    imageParameters.setImage(image);

    imageParameters.setxAxis(350);
    imageParameters.setyAxis(400);
    imageParameters.setWidth(200);
    imageParameters.setHeight(100);
    parameters.setImageParameters(imageParameters);
    SignatureImageTextParameters textParameters = new SignatureImageTextParameters();
    DSSFont font = new DSSJavaFont(Font.SERIF);
    font.setSize(16); // Specifies the text size value (the default font size is 12pt)
    textParameters.setFont(font);
    textParameters.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

    textParameters.setSignerTextPosition(SignerTextPosition.RIGHT);
    // Specifies a horizontal alignment of a text with respect to its area
    textParameters.setSignerTextHorizontalAlignment(SignerTextHorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
    // Specifies a vertical alignment of a text block with respect to a signature field area
    textParameters.setSignerTextVerticalAlignment(SignerTextVerticalAlignment.TOP);
    imageParameters.setTextParameters(textParameters);

    FileDocument fileToSign = new FileDocument("file.pdf");
    RemoteDocument fileSign = RemoteDocumentConverter.toRemoteDocument(fileToSign);
    DSSDocument toSignDocument = RemoteDocumentConverter.toDSSDocument(fileSign);

    byte[] hash = pdfSignatureService.digest(toSignDocument, parameters);

    DSSDocument signatureValue = SignHashDocument.signHash(hash);

    DSSDocument signedDocument = pdfSignatureService.sign(toSignDocument, DSSUtils.toByteArray(signatureValue), parameters);

    save(signedDocument);
```

****** Hash signature ********

```
     // Create common certificate verifier
    CommonCertificateVerifier commonCertificateVerifier = new CommonCertificateVerifier();
        // Create CAdESService for signature
    CAdESService service = new CAdESService(commonCertificateVerifier);

    CAdESSignatureParameters parameters = new CAdESSignatureParameters();
    DSSPrivateKeyEntry privateKey = getKey("certificate.p12","123456");


    // We choose the level of the signature (-B, -T, -LT, -LTA).
    parameters.setSignatureLevel(SignatureLevel.CAdES_BASELINE_B);
    parameters.setSignaturePackaging(SignaturePackaging.ENVELOPING);

    parameters.setDigestAlgorithm(DigestAlgorithm.SHA512);
    // We set the signing certificate
    parameters.setSigningCertificate(privateKey.getCertificate());
    // We set the certificate chain
    parameters.setCertificateChain(privateKey.getCertificateChain());


    SignatureTokenConnection signingToken = new Pkcs12SignatureToken("certificate.p12",
            new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("123456".toCharArray()));


    convertByteArrayToFile(hashToSign,"filetosign.hash");
    FileDocument fileToSign = new FileDocument("filetosign.hash");
    RemoteDocument fileSign = RemoteDocumentConverter.toRemoteDocument(fileToSign);
    DSSDocument toSignDocument = RemoteDocumentConverter.toDSSDocument(fileSign);

    //ToBeSigned dataToSign = service.getDataToSign(toSignDocument, parameters);

    ToBeSigned dataToSign = new ToBeSigned(hashToSign);

    DigestAlgorithm digestAlgorithm = parameters.getDigestAlgorithm();
    SignatureValue signatureValue = signingToken.sign(dataToSign, digestAlgorithm, privateKey);

    DSSDocument signedDocument = service.signDocument(toSignDocument, parameters, signatureValue);

    return  signedDocument;
```

******** PDF ERROR : *********

[image]

Comment: You mention that your solution runs on two interacting servers. It is unclear which parts of the code you show run on which server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## In general

*This was written in response to the original revision of your question.*

Your code mentions PAdES. Thus, I assume you mean integrated PAdES (not detached CAdES or XAdES) signatures when you say you're *trying to sign a PDF document with DSS.*

Creating integrated PDF signatures (like PAdES) requires first preparing the PDF to be able to carry an embedded signature, i.e. adding a signature dictionary to an existing or new signature field. This signature dictionary contains multiple information, signing time, signing reason, etc., and also a placeholder for embedding a CMS signature container later. Then this prepared PDF (except the placeholder) is hashed.

Furthermore, your code mentions that you *choose the level of the signature (-B, -T, -LT, -LTA)*.

Creating PAdES Baseline LT and PAdES Baseline LTA signatures requires preparing a PDF with a PAdES Baseline T signature and adding a collection of additional objects, depending on the nature of the T signature.

eSig DSS can do all this preparing for you **if it has the PDF to prepare**.

So if you only want to send a hash value from server A to B, you have to use eSig DSS on your server A to do most of the work, and server B only serves as a dumb signing service returning a signed hash value or at most a CMS container usable for PAdES.

Whether you can do this without server A knowing about the certificate, depends on whether you want certificate details to appear in a signature widget for the new signature or not. Creating the widget appearance is part of the PDF preparation step, so if you want such a widget with certificate information, server A needs to know the certificate, usually even *before requesting the signature*!

What kind of protocol you run between server A and B then, is up to you. You merely have to implement `SignatureTokenConnection` accordingly to use on server A in eSig DSS to communicate with server B.

## In case of your approach

*After you now showed code from both servers, one can discuss your specific approach.*

On server A you use eSig DSS to prepare a PAdES signature and embed a CMS signature container with the `SignatureValue` your `SignHashDocument.signHash` call returns:

```java
ToBeSigned dataToSign = service.getDataToSign(toSignDocument, parameters);

SignatureValue signatureValue = SignHashDocument.signHash(dataToSign);

DSSDocument signedDocument = service.signDocument(toSignDocument, parameters, signatureValue);
```

I.e. server A creates the CMS signature container and server B only supplies the signed hash.

**This cannot work unless you know the certificate used for signing and set it in the `parameters` before the `service.getDataToSign` call.**

The reason is that the CMS container contains references to that certificate in both the unsigned bytes and (for PAdES) the signed bytes of the container. For the reference in the unsigned bytes it theoretically would suffice to retrieve the certificate together with the signature bytes, but for the reference in the signed bytes it has to be known beforehand.

Alternatively you can try to implement the full generation of the CMS container on server B.

This requires considerable changes, though, and you have to dive quite a bit deeper into the `PAdESService` sources. Instead of the three lines quoted above on server A you have to:

- first retrieve a PDF object library and PDF signature service

  ```
  IPdfObjFactory pdfObjFactory = new ServiceLoaderPdfObjFactory();
  PDFSignatureService pdfSignatureService = pdfObjFactory.newPAdESSignatureService();
  ```
- prepare the PDF a first time for signing and calculate the *document digest*,

  ```
  byte[] hash = pdfSignatureService.digest(toSignDocument, parameters);
  ```
- send this document digest to the backend (server B) which must create and return a special CAdES signature container, not merely naked signature bytes,
- and prepare the PDF a second time for signing and inject this signature container:

  ```
  DSSDocument signature = pdfSignatureService.sign(toSignDocument, encodedData, parameters);
  ```

## A proof of concept

Here a proof of concept using eSig DSS 5.8:

On your server A we can essentially use your existing code:

```java
DSSDocument toSignDocument = PDF_DOCUMENT_TO_SIGN;
DSSDocument image = IMAGE_DOCUMENT;


PAdESSignatureParameters parameters = new PAdESSignatureParameters();
parameters.setDigestAlgorithm(DigestAlgorithm.SHA512);
parameters.setReason("Preuve de signature");
parameters.setLocation("MAROC");
parameters.setGenerateTBSWithoutCertificate(true);

SignatureImageParameters imageParameters = new SignatureImageParameters();
imageParameters.setPage(1);
imageParameters.setImage(image);
imageParameters.setxAxis(350);
imageParameters.setyAxis(400);
imageParameters.setWidth(200);
imageParameters.setHeight(100);
parameters.setImageParameters(imageParameters);

SignatureImageTextParameters textParameters = new SignatureImageTextParameters();
DSSFont font = new DSSJavaFont(Font.SERIF);
font.setSize(16);
textParameters.setFont(font);
textParameters.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
textParameters.setSignerTextPosition(SignerTextPosition.RIGHT);
textParameters.setSignerTextHorizontalAlignment(SignerTextHorizontalAlignment.LEFT);
textParameters.setSignerTextVerticalAlignment(SignerTextVerticalAlignment.TOP);
textParameters.setText("TESTING");
imageParameters.setTextParameters(textParameters);


IPdfObjFactory pdfObjFactory = new ServiceLoaderPdfObjFactory();
PDFSignatureService pdfSignatureService = pdfObjFactory.newPAdESSignatureService();

byte[] hash = pdfSignatureService.digest(toSignDocument, parameters);

byte[] signatureValue = signHash(hash);

DSSDocument signedDocument = pdfSignatureService.sign(toSignDocument, signatureValue, parameters);


signedDocument.save(PATH_TO_SAVE_THE_SIGNED_DOCUMENT_TO);
```

*([SplitPAdESSigning](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-sd-dss5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/sddss5/sign/SplitPAdESSigning.java#L97) test `testSplitPAdESGenerationForMehdi`)*

The method `signHash` now shall independently create a CMS signature container for the given document hash, and this container shall conform to PAdES requirements. eSig DSS contains methods and classes providing this functionality but they `protected` or even less visible. Thus, for our POC we simply copy them into our code.

For simplicity I use hard coded SHA512withRSA as signing algorithm.

Thus:

```java
byte[] signHash(byte[] hash) throws IOException {
    Pkcs12SignatureToken signingToken = new Pkcs12SignatureToken(YOUR_P12_DATA);
    DSSPrivateKeyEntry privateKey = signingToken.getKey(YOUR_ALIAS);

    CommonCertificateVerifier commonCertificateVerifier = new CommonCertificateVerifier();
    padesCMSSignedDataBuilder = new PadesCMSSignedDataBuilder(commonCertificateVerifier);

    PAdESSignatureParameters parameters = new PAdESSignatureParameters();
    parameters.setDigestAlgorithm(DigestAlgorithm.SHA512);
    parameters.setEncryptionAlgorithm(EncryptionAlgorithm.RSA);
    parameters.setSignatureLevel(SignatureLevel.PAdES_BASELINE_B);
    parameters.setSigningCertificate(privateKey.getCertificate());

    ToBeSigned dataToSign = getDataToSign(hash, parameters);
    SignatureValue signatureValue = signingToken.sign(dataToSign, DigestAlgorithm.SHA512, privateKey);
    return generateCMSSignedData(hash, parameters, signatureValue);
}

PadesCMSSignedDataBuilder padesCMSSignedDataBuilder;
```

*([SplitPAdESSigning](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-sd-dss5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/sddss5/sign/SplitPAdESSigning.java#L148) method)*

The helper methods `getDataToSign` and `generateCMSSignedData` are essentially copied from `PAdESService`; they use the `padesCMSSignedDataBuilder` provided by `signHash` (instead of a member variable you can also make it another argument of these two methods):

```java
/** @see eu.europa.esig.dss.pades.signature.PAdESService#getDataToSign(DSSDocument, PAdESSignatureParameters) */
public ToBeSigned getDataToSign(byte[] messageDigest, final PAdESSignatureParameters parameters) throws DSSException {
    final SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = parameters.getSignatureAlgorithm();
    final CustomContentSigner customContentSigner = new CustomContentSigner(signatureAlgorithm.getJCEId());

    SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder signerInfoGeneratorBuilder = padesCMSSignedDataBuilder.getSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(parameters, messageDigest);

    final CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = padesCMSSignedDataBuilder.createCMSSignedDataGenerator(parameters, customContentSigner,
            signerInfoGeneratorBuilder, null);

    final CMSProcessableByteArray content = new CMSProcessableByteArray(messageDigest);

    CMSUtils.generateDetachedCMSSignedData(generator, content);

    final byte[] dataToSign = customContentSigner.getOutputStream().toByteArray();
    return new ToBeSigned(dataToSign);
}

/** @see eu.europa.esig.dss.pades.signature.PAdESService#generateCMSSignedData(DSSDocument, PAdESSignatureParameters, SignatureValue) */
protected byte[] generateCMSSignedData(byte[] messageDigest, final PAdESSignatureParameters parameters,
        final SignatureValue signatureValue) {
    final SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = parameters.getSignatureAlgorithm();
    final SignatureLevel signatureLevel = parameters.getSignatureLevel();
    Objects.requireNonNull(signatureAlgorithm, "SignatureAlgorithm cannot be null!");
    Objects.requireNonNull(signatureLevel, "SignatureLevel must be defined!");
    
    final CustomContentSigner customContentSigner = new CustomContentSigner(signatureAlgorithm.getJCEId(), signatureValue.getValue());
    
    final SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder signerInfoGeneratorBuilder = padesCMSSignedDataBuilder.getSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(parameters, messageDigest);
    
    final CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = padesCMSSignedDataBuilder.createCMSSignedDataGenerator(parameters, customContentSigner,
    signerInfoGeneratorBuilder, null);
    
    final CMSProcessableByteArray content = new CMSProcessableByteArray(messageDigest);
    CMSSignedData data = CMSUtils.generateDetachedCMSSignedData(generator, content);

    return DSSASN1Utils.getDEREncoded(data);
}
```

*([SplitPAdESSigning](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-sd-dss5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/sddss5/sign/SplitPAdESSigning.java#L172) methods)*

The classes `PadesCMSSignedDataBuilder` and `PAdESLevelBaselineB` due to restricted visibility are copied along:

```java
/** @see eu.europa.esig.dss.cades.signature.CMSSignedDataBuilder */
class PadesCMSSignedDataBuilder extends CMSSignedDataBuilder {
    public PadesCMSSignedDataBuilder(CertificateVerifier certificateVerifier) {
        super(certificateVerifier);
    }

    @Override
    protected CMSSignedDataGenerator createCMSSignedDataGenerator(CAdESSignatureParameters parameters, ContentSigner contentSigner, SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder signerInfoGeneratorBuilder,
            CMSSignedData originalSignedData) throws DSSException {

        return super.createCMSSignedDataGenerator(parameters, contentSigner, signerInfoGeneratorBuilder, originalSignedData);
    }

    protected SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder getSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(final PAdESSignatureParameters parameters, final byte[] messageDigest) {
        final CAdESLevelBaselineB cadesLevelBaselineB = new CAdESLevelBaselineB(true);
        final PAdESLevelBaselineB padesProfileB = new PAdESLevelBaselineB();

        final DigestCalculatorProvider digestCalculatorProvider = new BcDigestCalculatorProvider();

        SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder signerInfoGeneratorBuilder = new SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(digestCalculatorProvider);

        signerInfoGeneratorBuilder = signerInfoGeneratorBuilder.setSignedAttributeGenerator(new CMSAttributeTableGenerator() {
            @Override
            public AttributeTable getAttributes(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map params) throws CMSAttributeTableGenerationException {
                return padesProfileB.getSignedAttributes(params, cadesLevelBaselineB, parameters, messageDigest);
            }
        });

        signerInfoGeneratorBuilder = signerInfoGeneratorBuilder.setUnsignedAttributeGenerator(new CMSAttributeTableGenerator() {
            @Override
            public AttributeTable getAttributes(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map params) throws CMSAttributeTableGenerationException {
                return padesProfileB.getUnsignedAttributes();
            }
        });

        return signerInfoGeneratorBuilder;
    }
}

/** @see eu.europa.esig.dss.pades.signature.PAdESLevelBaselineB */
class PAdESLevelBaselineB {
    AttributeTable getSignedAttributes(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map params, 
            CAdESLevelBaselineB cadesProfile, PAdESSignatureParameters parameters, byte[] messageDigest) {
        AttributeTable signedAttributes = cadesProfile.getSignedAttributes(parameters);

        if (signedAttributes.get(CMSAttributes.contentType) == null) {
            ASN1ObjectIdentifier contentType = (ASN1ObjectIdentifier) params.get(CMSAttributeTableGenerator.CONTENT_TYPE);
            if (contentType != null) {
                signedAttributes = signedAttributes.add(CMSAttributes.contentType, contentType);
            }
        }

        if (signedAttributes.get(CMSAttributes.messageDigest) == null) {
            signedAttributes = signedAttributes.add(CMSAttributes.messageDigest, new DEROctetString(messageDigest));
        }

        return signedAttributes;
    }

    AttributeTable getUnsignedAttributes() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

*([SplitPAdESSigning](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-sd-dss5/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/sddss5/sign/SplitPAdESSigning.java#L211) helper classes)*

`signHash` and its helpers do not depend on the server A code and, therefore, also can be located on server B.

Comment: Thank you for your support and usual help! The error I encounter is in the PAdES Signature Parameters object which requires the existence of the certificate otherwise I get the following error  : Signing Certificate is not defined! 

Error line : ToBeSigned dataToSign = service.getDataToSign(toSignDocument, parameters);

Comment: At that point it should suffice if you called `parameters.setGenerateTBSWithoutCertificate(true)` beforehand.

Comment: when I set setGenerateTBSWithoutCertificate to true I have an error at the pdf level which says that the signature is not valid. he does not recognize the signer

Comment: Then please explain more clearly what you do. In the code you shared you do set a certificate. Furthermore, that code apparently is all running only on one machine. In other words, the problem you write about simply cannot occur. So please show the code that actually fails, and also share an example PDF illustrating the failure.

Comment: I just made an update on the source code used

Comment: I just added some words on your new code in my answer in section "In case of your approach"

Comment: and is there some change i need to apply on server B or i keep the same implementation ? . By what I just applied these changes and I have the same error

Comment: As mentioned in my edit, *the backend (server B) which must create and return a special CAdES signature container, not merely naked signature bytes,* so yes, you have to change that code to create a CAdES / CMS signature container (including the appropriate certificate references) instead of the naked signature value you create currently.

Comment: I just made these changes and I have the same errors, can you please see the UPDATE I just made on my source code

Comment: As far as I can see in your updated code, you still don't return a CAdES / CMS signature container but a naked signature value. You have to create a CMS signature container on server B.

Comment: Do you have any documentation that allows you to do this ?  I'm still a beginner in signing

Comment: After a little research I can now reintegrate the signature but I have the following error on the PDF. (Error in update)

Comment: If I find some time the next days I'll try and write a little poc for this.

Comment: But otherwise you think it has errors on the effected implementation ??

Comment: I'll post the proof-of-concept tomorrow. And yes, your implementation of server b has errors.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help @mkl ! But can you take a look at the answer I just posted please ?

Comment: *"But can you take a look at the answer I just posted please ?"* - Looks ok. Just like in my POC you essentially used the DSS methods and classes that generate the PAdES CMS container, you merely overcame visibility issues differently.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help MKL, but I have a quick question how can we get the prepared document back (with signature area, but before it's signed)

Comment: Which document version exactly do you have and which version do you exactly want to go back to? You sound like you have the finished, signed pdf and want the revision already with a signature dictionary but the **Contents** value still being a placeholder filled with zeros instead of a signature container. This would merely require setting the **Contents** value to just zeros again and (if you meanwhile extended the signature) truncating at the end of the revision signed by the signature.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, I have a question, if I would like to add timestamp? can you help me with this?

Comment: @eluish192 *" I have a question, if I would like to add timestamp? can you help me with this?"* - as the topic question here was about split signing on two servers A and B, on which of those servers  do you want to add what kind of time stamp?

Comment: @mkl hi thanks for your response, I would like a timestamp on any of the servers, I tried to add it where the hash signature is made by setting the signaturelevel to T and adding a tspSource but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 2):

After some research on the github dss esig repository I was able to find a solution that seemed correct :

********************* ON SERVER A **********************

```
public class ServerA {
private static PAdESSignatureParameters signatureParameters;
private static DSSDocument documentToSign;
public static ExternalCMSPAdESService service;


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    documentToSign = new FileDocument(new File("file.pdf"));

    signatureParameters = new PAdESSignatureParameters();
    signatureParameters.setSignatureLevel(SignatureLevel.PAdES_BASELINE_B);
    signatureParameters.setLocation("Luxembourg");
    signatureParameters.setReason("DSS testing");
    signatureParameters.setContactInfo("Jira");
    signatureParameters.setGenerateTBSWithoutCertificate(true);

    service = new ExternalCMSPAdESService(getOfflineCertificateVerifier());
    byte[] documentDigest = computeDocumentDigest(documentToSign, signatureParameters);

    // Embedded CAdES is generated by a third party
    byte[] cmsSignedData = ServerB.getSignedCMSignedData(documentDigest);

    service.setCmsSignedData(cmsSignedData);
    DSSDocument finalDoc = service.signDocument(documentToSign, signatureParameters, null);

    save(finalDoc);
}

private static void save(DSSDocument signedDocument) {
    try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("DSS.pdf")) {
        Utils.copy(signedDocument.openStream(), fos);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, "Unable to save file : " + e.getMessage(), ButtonType.CLOSE);
        alert.showAndWait();
        return;
    }
}

public static CertificateVerifier getOfflineCertificateVerifier() {
    CertificateVerifier cv = new CommonCertificateVerifier();
    cv.setDataLoader(new IgnoreDataLoader());
    return cv;
}

protected static byte[] computeDocumentDigest(final DSSDocument toSignDocument, final PAdESSignatureParameters parameters) {
    IPdfObjFactory pdfObjFactory = new ServiceLoaderPdfObjFactory();
    final PDFSignatureService pdfSignatureService = pdfObjFactory.newPAdESSignatureService();
    return pdfSignatureService.digest(toSignDocument, parameters);
}

private static class ExternalCMSPAdESService extends PAdESService {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2003453716888412577L;

    private byte[] cmsSignedData;

    public ExternalCMSPAdESService(CertificateVerifier certificateVerifier) {
        super(certificateVerifier);
    }

    @Override
    protected byte[] generateCMSSignedData(final DSSDocument toSignDocument, final PAdESSignatureParameters parameters,
                                           final SignatureValue signatureValue) {
        if (this.cmsSignedData == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("A CMS signed data must be provided");
        }
        return this.cmsSignedData;
    }

    public void setCmsSignedData(final byte[] cmsSignedData) {
        this.cmsSignedData = cmsSignedData;
    }

}
}
```

And to be able to sign the calculated hash :

********************* ON SERVER B **********************

```
public class ServerB {

private static PAdESSignatureParameters signatureParameters;
private static DSSDocument documentToSign;
public static ExternalCMSPAdESService service;

/**
 * Computes a CAdES with specific things for PAdES
 */
public static byte[] getSignedCMSignedData(byte[] documentDigest) throws Exception {
    signatureParameters = new PAdESSignatureParameters();
    signatureParameters.setSigningCertificate(getSigningCert());
    signatureParameters.setCertificateChain(getCertificateChain());
    signatureParameters.setSignatureLevel(SignatureLevel.PAdES_BASELINE_B);
    signatureParameters.setLocation("Luxembourg");
    signatureParameters.setReason("DSS testing");
    signatureParameters.setContactInfo("Jira");

    CMSProcessableByteArray content = new CMSProcessableByteArray(documentDigest);

    PadesCMSSignedDataBuilder padesCMSSignedDataBuilder = new PadesCMSSignedDataBuilder(getOfflineCertificateVerifier());
    SignatureAlgorithm signatureAlgorithm = signatureParameters.getSignatureAlgorithm();

    CustomContentSigner customContentSigner = new CustomContentSigner(signatureAlgorithm.getJCEId());
    SignerInfoGeneratorBuilder signerInfoGeneratorBuilder = padesCMSSignedDataBuilder.getSignerInfoGeneratorBuilder(signatureParameters, documentDigest);

    CMSSignedDataGenerator generator = padesCMSSignedDataBuilder.createCMSSignedDataGenerator(signatureParameters, customContentSigner,
            signerInfoGeneratorBuilder, null);

    CMSUtils.generateDetachedCMSSignedData(generator, content);

    SignatureTokenConnection signingToken = new Pkcs12SignatureToken("certificate.p12",
            new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("123456".toCharArray()));
    DSSPrivateKeyEntry privateKey = getKey("certificate.p12","123456");

    SignatureValue signatureValue = signingToken.sign(new ToBeSigned(customContentSigner.getOutputStream().toByteArray()),
            signatureParameters.getDigestAlgorithm(), privateKey);

    customContentSigner = new CustomContentSigner(signatureAlgorithm.getJCEId(), signatureValue.getValue());
    generator = padesCMSSignedDataBuilder.createCMSSignedDataGenerator(signatureParameters, customContentSigner, signerInfoGeneratorBuilder, null);

    CMSSignedData cmsSignedData = CMSUtils.generateDetachedCMSSignedData(generator, content);
    return DSSASN1Utils.getDEREncoded(cmsSignedData);
}

public static CertificateVerifier getOfflineCertificateVerifier() {
    CertificateVerifier cv = new CommonCertificateVerifier();
    cv.setDataLoader(new IgnoreDataLoader());
    return cv;
}

public static List<CertificateToken> getCertificateChain() throws Exception {
    List<CertificateToken> list = new ArrayList<>();
    CertificateToken[] l = getKey("certificate.p12","123456").getCertificateChain();
    for (int i = 0; i < l.length; i++) {
        list.add(l[i]);
    }
    return list;
}

public static CertificateToken getSigningCert() throws Exception {
    return getKey("certificate.p12","123456").getCertificate();
}

public static DSSPrivateKeyEntry getKey(String certificate, String pin) throws Exception {
    try (Pkcs12SignatureToken signatureToken = new Pkcs12SignatureToken("certificate.p12",
            new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("123456".toCharArray()))) {
        List<DSSPrivateKeyEntry> keys = signatureToken.getKeys();
        KSPrivateKeyEntry dssPrivateKeyEntry = (KSPrivateKeyEntry) keys.get(0);
        DSSPrivateKeyEntry entry = signatureToken.getKey(dssPrivateKeyEntry.getAlias(),
                new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("123456".toCharArray()));
        return entry;
    }
}
private static class ExternalCMSPAdESService extends PAdESService {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2003453716888412577L;

    private byte[] cmsSignedData;

    public ExternalCMSPAdESService(CertificateVerifier certificateVerifier) {
        super(certificateVerifier);
    }

    @Override
    protected byte[] generateCMSSignedData(final DSSDocument toSignDocument, final PAdESSignatureParameters parameters,
                                           final SignatureValue signatureValue) {
        if (this.cmsSignedData == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("A CMS signed data must be provided");
        }
        return this.cmsSignedData;
    }

    public void setCmsSignedData(final byte[] cmsSignedData) {
        this.cmsSignedData = cmsSignedData;
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Indeed, instead of copying hidden methods and helpers as I did in the poc in my answer, you can also tweak the `PAdESService` like this to use an externally generated CMS. One remark, though: You use the `PadesCMSSignedDataBuilder`. That class is package protected in eSig DSS, though. To access it, therefore, you have to put your code into the same package. Or you actually also (like my POC) access a copy of the DSS class.

Comment: Alright, that's exactly what I wanted to know. On the other hand during the integration I had another blockage. On my process I prepare the document for signature and I store the hash that is going to be signed and subsequently the client signs the document and at the end I reinstate the signed hash. The problem here is that the PAdESSignatureParameters object does not contain the same values used during the preparation thing which gives an invalid signature

Comment: *"The problem here is that the PAdESSignatureParameters object does not contain the same values"* - Obviously it has to.

Comment: In fact because me in my process I prepare the document I make it visualize to the client and then I send for signature and the third step I reintegrate the document in the original document and in this step I use a new Object PAdESSignatureParameters

Comment: since this happens on two separate step so I can't reuse the same object

Comment: @mkl do you have any idea about this problem please ?

Comment: You shouldn't need the same object, merely an object with the same values.

Comment: Exactly and so how can I store the used values and retrieve them later. I've been stuck in this point for 4 days lol

Comment: The signature parameter classes extend `Serializable`. Have you tried serializing/deserializing?

Comment: I tried to store the object in a JSON file in a first step and retrieve it afterwards but I have a lot of problems in deserializing !!

Comment: The signature parameter classes extend `Serializable`. Thus, Java built-in serialization with `ObjectOutputStream` and de-serialization with `ObjectInputStream` _should_ work.

Comment: have you any idea about adding timestamp in the signature ?

Comment: A signature timestamp in the CMS container? Or a document timestamp?

Comment: Yes, in the cms container. I want to add it in the server B

Comment: There is any solution that i can use it ??

Comment: Two options: You can either already extend the CMS container to a CAdES-T type (possible on either server), or you can extend the signed PDF to a PAdES-T type (only possible on server A).

Answer (score 0):

It's is possible and one open source full implementation can be seen in here https://github.com/eideasy/eideasy-external-pades-digital-signatures

You need to create PDF in same format as it will be after being signed, remove all signature ByteRange and then calculate hash.

After getting CAdES signature just add this to the ByteRange. This will give you up to baseline-T signature.

For baseline LT you need to add DSS with all the used certificates, OCSP responses and crls as well.

If more questions you can contact me using details in my profile.

Here is the most important part of the full application that will calculate the digest to be signed for you. When calculating digest then the signatureBytes can be new byte[0].

```
    public byte[] signDetached(SignatureParameters parameters, PDDocument document, byte[] signatureBytes, OutputStream out)
        throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    if (document.getDocumentId() == null) {
        document.setDocumentId(parameters.getSignatureTime());
    }

    PDSignature signature = createSignatureDictionary(parameters);
    SignatureOptions options = new SignatureOptions();

    // Enough room for signature, timestamp and OCSP for baseline-LT profile.
    options.setPreferredSignatureSize(SignatureOptions.DEFAULT_SIGNATURE_SIZE * 2);
    document.addSignature(signature, options);
    ExternalSigningSupport externalSigning = document.saveIncrementalForExternalSigning(out);

    byte[] dataToSign = IOUtils.toByteArray(externalSigning.getContent());
    final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    byte[] digestBytes = digest.digest(dataToSign);

    if (signatureBytes != null) {
        externalSigning.setSignature(signatureBytes);
    }

    return digestBytes;
}

private PDSignature createSignatureDictionary(final SignatureParameters parameters) {
    PDSignature signature = new PDSignature();

    signature.setType(COSName.getPDFName("Sig"));
    signature.setFilter(PDSignature.FILTER_ADOBE_PPKLITE);
    signature.setSubFilter(PDSignature.SUBFILTER_ETSI_CADES_DETACHED);

    if (notEmpty(parameters.getSignerName())) {
        signature.setName(parameters.getSignerName());
    }

    if (notEmpty(parameters.getContactInfo())) {
        signature.setContactInfo(parameters.getContactInfo());
    }

    if (notEmpty(parameters.getLocation())) {
        signature.setLocation(parameters.getLocation());
    }

    if (notEmpty(parameters.getReason())) {
        signature.setReason(parameters.getReason());
    }

    // the signing date, needed for valid signature
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    final Date signingDate = new Date(parameters.getSignatureTime());
    cal.setTime(signingDate);
    signature.setSignDate(cal);

    return signature;
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code here, not via link or separate contact. Currently your answer essentially is a link- only answer.

Comment: Thanks, its a good point. Added most important part of the code here.

Answer (score 0):

An example using IAIK to sign on HSM, and Europa DSS to asssemble PAdES file:

1/ prepare data to be signed using Europa DSS

```java
            CertificateFactory fact = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
            X509Certificate cer = null;
            try (FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream (certFile);) {
                cer = (X509Certificate) fact.generateCertificate(is);
            }

            CertificateToken certificateToken = new CertificateToken(cer);
            
            CertificateToken[] certificateChain = new CertificateToken[] {
                certificateToken
            };

            PAdESSignatureParameters parameters = buildPAdESSignatureParameters(certificateToken, certificateChain);
```

```java
    public static PAdESSignatureParameters buildPAdESSignatureParameters(
            CertificateToken signingCertificate,
            final CertificateToken... certificateChain) {
        PAdESSignatureParameters parameters = new PAdESSignatureParameters();
        // We choose the level of the signature (-B, -T, -LT, -LTA).
//      parameters.setSignatureLevel(SignatureLevel.PAdES_BASELINE_B);
        parameters.setSignatureLevel(SignatureLevel.PAdES_BASELINE_T);
//      parameters.setSignatureLevel(SignatureLevel.PAdES_BASELINE_LT);
//      parameters.setSignatureLevel(SignatureLevel.PAdES_BASELINE_LTA);
        parameters.setReason("Preuve de signature");
        parameters.setLocation("PARIS");
        parameters.setSigningCertificate(signingCertificate);
        parameters.setCertificateChain(certificateChain);

        return parameters;
    }
```

2/ sign with HSM (Bull Proteccio for example) with IAIK

```java
            String modulePath = "C:/data/applications/HSM/europa_dss/win64/nethsm.dll";

            iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.Module module = iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.Module.getInstance(modulePath);
            module.initialize(null);

            Token token = retrieveToken(slotId, module);
            System.out.println("module: " + infoModule(module));
            
            Session session = null;
            session = openSession(token, pincode);

            // Get the SignedInfo segment that need to be signed.
            DSSDocument toSignDocument = new FileDocument(toSignFile);
            ToBeSigned dataToSign = service.getDataToSign(toSignDocument, parameters);

            byte[] content = dataToSign.getBytes();
            System.out.println("parameters: " + parameters);
            
            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(content);
            ByteBuffer signedData = signDataByKeyIdAndLabel(keyId, label, byteBuffer, session);
            byte[] cmsContent = signedData.array();
            
            System.out.println("signed data: " + Hex.encodeHexString( signedData.array() ) );
            System.out.println("signing date: " + parameters.getSigningDate());
            System.out.println("signing time: " + parameters.getSigningDate().getTime());
                        
            
            Key hsmPublicKey = findPublicKeyByIDAndLabel(session, keyId, label);
            boolean verify = verifyHSM(session, hsmPublicKey, content, cmsContent);
            System.out.println("public key: " + hsmPublicKey);
            System.out.println("public key (cer): " + cer);
            System.out.println("verify: " + verify);
            
            closeSession(session);
```

```java
    private byte[] signHSM(Session session, Key key, byte[] data) throws TokenException {
        session.signInit(Mechanism.get(PKCS11Constants.CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS), key);
        return session.sign(data);
    }
    
    private boolean verifyHSM(Session session, Key key, byte[] data, byte[] signature) {
        try {
            session.verifyInit(Mechanism.get(PKCS11Constants.CKM_SHA256_RSA_PKCS), key);
            session.verify(data, signature);
            return true;
        } catch (TokenException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

3/ Assemble

```java
assemble(
                    parameters,
                    cmsContent, 
                    toSignFile, 
                    signedFile,
                    service);
```

```java
    public static void assemble(
            PAdESSignatureParameters parameters,
            byte[] signatureValueBytes,
            File toSignFile,
            File signedFile,
            PAdESService service) 
    throws IOException {
        DSSDocument toSignDocument = new FileDocument(toSignFile);
        
        SignatureValue signatureValue = new SignatureValue(SignatureAlgorithm.RSA_SHA256, signatureValueBytes);
        DSSDocument signedDocument = service.signDocument(toSignDocument, parameters, signatureValue);
        signedDocument.save(signedFile.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```